# Add article to transaction replication without generating a snapshot at all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have a transaction replication and the subscription was synced from snapshot years ago.  Now I have a new table that needs to be added to the replication.  Problem is the table is close to a TB and I do not want to generate a snapshot for that table instead just want the new data to be synced, kinda like when you sync from backup.  Its inserts only to the table and I can sync the old data manually later.

How do I make replication to start transferring the data without generating the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't a supported way to do what you are asking. You can use a backup/restore but that would be to a new database. You could try a filtered article where you only grab data after a certain create date.

Or you could use a manual process such as an SSIS package or T-SQL Scripts to stage the schema and data. But the snapshot is more or less a required item.

I would probably do a single article snapshot or maybe look to filter if you can filter create_date > getdate() and then add in rows manually after if you have such a column, or an identity column, etc.

A few links:

[About manually preparing.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151246.aspx)

[About using backups or other methods.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151705.aspx)

[About filtering.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151775.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to look for is 'initializing a subscriber manually'.  To do this you can setup your subscriber to use a option of `@sync_type = 'replication support only'` and this let's the system know you have manually prepped the environment yourself already.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151246.aspx) is Microsoft's documentation on initializing a subscriber manually.

Be careful of ID conflicts obviously as you are bypassing everything the system checks and telling it you are certain everything is already synced and to just start replicating.

In this case you never even need to run the snapshot agent for that publication if it's already good to go.  This [article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Replication/88155/) gives you more of a background.

Edit to question and answer below in questions:

[Looks like](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/repltalk/2011/03/14/how-to-add-an-article-to-an-existing-transactional-subscription-initialized-through-backup/) you will want to go with the plan discussed in comments where you setup a new publication.  If you have full control from both sides and can stop all transactions you might want to just redo the subscription and publication to include everything and do a @sync_type = 'replication support only'.  Or make a 2nd publication with that table as your article and send that out with replication support only as 2 options you have.

Comment: The subscription is already there and it was initially from a snapshot when it was originally setup.  Now I am trying to add a new article and wanna avoid generating snapshot.

Comment: Would setting up a new publication completely with that 1 table and setting up the subscribers without snapshot work for you?  Also I'm pretty sure you can update a subscription, let me look for you but what do you think of option 1?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151705(v=sql.120).aspx) article. To quote:

> Restore the backup on the Subscriber, and then the Distribution Agent copies any required replication metadata and system procedures. Initializing with a backup is the fastest way to deliver data to the Subscriber and is convenient, because any recent backup can be used if it was taken after the publication was enabled for initialization with a backup.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old and good solution
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Replication/119650/. Works like magic for me every time I use it.

exec sp_changepublication
        @publication=N'testWOM'
      , @property=N'allow_anonymous'
      , @value='false';
go
exec sp_changepublication
        @publication=N'testWOM'
      , @property=N'immediate_sync'
      , @value='false';
go